# z-index of DIV positioned on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I have two div containers which are structured as follows:

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <img src="images/point.png" class="img-a1">
    Lots of text goes here.
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
    <img src="images/point.png" class="img-b1">
    Some more text goes here
</div>
```

The styles associated with this are as follows:

```
.outer-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 500px;
}
.img-a1 {
    float:left; 
    z-index:-1; 
    position:relative; 
    margin-left: 250px; 
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}
.img-b1 {
    float:right; 
    z-index:-1; 
    position:relative; 
    margin-left: 250px; 
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}
```

The result of this is to produce something like the following, where `|||` is the text from div-a and `...` is the text from div-b:

```
.....|||||
.....|||||
.....|||||
.....|||||
```

However, since the second div is placed immediately above the first div, none of the text in the second div can be selected, although it can be seen since there is just empty space, and a 1x1 px image above it.

Is there a way to get the text from the lower div to be selectable, without making the upper div unselectable?

Comment: in the future, please create your own jsfiddle, here is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/LZh8A/1/

Comment: `Is there a way to get the text from the lower div to be selectable, without making the upper div unselectable?` - how can the user or browser differentiate which text should be selected when you're trying to select one of two things that are on top of each other? :S

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but I'm sure if you explained your desired result we could give you a better idea.

Comment: @thirtydot @anothershrubery The text never overlaps. The purpose of the images is to make the text wrap around it. I want the images, though, to have the lowest z-index relative to all the text, so that if you select over the images, you would be selecting the text which is behind it.

Comment: @Jacub thanks for creating the jsfiddle - forgot about doing that as I've been off this site for a while, and just get back.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your structure, there's no way to select text from the first div, since the second one is positioned on top of it.

However I think you can change your CSS to have the same results and without overlapping the two divs. I propose some think like this :

HTML:

```
<div class="right-div">
    <img src="images/point.png" class="img-a1">
    Lots of text goes here.
</div>
<div class="left-div">
    <img src="images/point.png" class="img-b1">
    Some more text goes here
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.left-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
}

.right-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}

.img-a1 {
    float:left; 
    z-index:-1; 
    position:relative; 
    background: red;    
}
.img-b1 {
    z-index:-1; 
    position:absolute; 
    margin-left: 500px; 
    background: blue;
}
```

The rendering is pretty much the same as your example, and you can select both of the texts without any problems.

It is possible that you'll have to adapt the margins depending on the size of your images.

Comment: @Krtek the purposes of the images is to force the text to wrap a particular way. The page on which I'm using this has several such DIV sections, each with it's own set of alignments. With only 2, something like this would work, but there are 9 sections....

Comment: It may be better if you post the complete layout of your page, and maybe a little mock-up of want you want to do :)

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle link Jakub posted in his comment on my post, and you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, with 2 divs, and my css gives exactly the same result, but you said there's more than 2 divs, so without the exact layout, it's really difficult to help ;)

Comment: I'll put in a more complete layout in a couple minutes.

Comment: Update complete with a 3 div layout.

Comment: Just realized that the link is to the top level, not the current version: http://jsfiddle.net/LZh8A/14/